# I got a error after installing phpmyadmin ( pic inside )

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a vps on centos 7 64x with webmin/virtualmin/LAMP.

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin but I got this error (Attached Image)

[you need a zoom becuase this is all the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTzin.jpg)

How can I solve it?

Comment: doesn't look like PHP's being interpreted.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error message?  I briefly read through it and there are some conditions which are triggering the error-  are you logged on as root without a password?